# why isn't the CAShapeLayer showing up sometimes?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, uiview

I am using the following custom UIView class as a loading indicator in my app. Most of the time it works great and I can just uses `loadingView.startLoading()` to make it appear. However, in rare cases, only the UIView appears with a shadow behind it, and the CAShapeLayer is nowhere to be seen. What could be preventing the CAShapeLayer from appearing on top of the LoadingView UIView?

**LoadingView**

```
class LoadingView: UIView {
    
//MARK: - Properties and Init
    
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var circlePath : UIBezierPath = .init()
    let size : CGFloat = 80
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
        tag = 100
        addShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.label.cgColor, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), shadowOpacity: 0.3, shadowRadius: 3)
        backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        calculateCirclePath()
        animateCircle(duration: 1, repeats: true)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
//MARK: - Private UI Setup Methods
    
    private func calculateCirclePath() {
        self.circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: size / 2, y: size / 2), radius: size / 3, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        circleLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
    }
    
    private func animateCircle(duration: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool) {
        // Setup the CAShapeLayer with the path, colors, and line width
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
        
        // Don't draw the circle initially
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        
        // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.repeatCount = repeats ? .infinity : 1
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        circleLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
        
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeats ? .infinity : 1
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi*3
        rotationAnimation.duration = duration
        rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        circleLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
        
        let fadeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeAnimation.repeatCount = repeats ? .infinity : 1
        fadeAnimation.fromValue = 1
        fadeAnimation.toValue = 0
        fadeAnimation.duration = duration
        fadeAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        circleLayer.add(fadeAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

**Extension for ViewController**

```
extension ViewController {
    func startLoading() {
            view.addSubview(loadingView)
            loadingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                loadingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                loadingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                loadingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(80)),
                loadingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(80)),
            ])
        loadingView.isHidden = false
    }
    
    func stopLoading() {
        loadingView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this ever works. You cannot add a sublayer and animate it all in one go.

Comment: @matt you're right, I made a change so they weren't done at the same time and it fixed it. Why can't a sublayer and animation happen all in one go?

Answer (score 0):

Because a sublayer and animation can't happen in one go, I changed the code to what is shown below and now it works perfectly!

**LoadingView**

```
class LoadingView: UIView {
    
//MARK: - Properties and Init
    
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var circlePath : UIBezierPath = .init()
    let size : CGFloat = 80
    
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
        tag = 100
        addShadow(shadowColor: UIColor.label.cgColor, shadowOffset: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0), shadowOpacity: 0.3, shadowRadius: 3)
        backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        layer.cornerRadius = size/8
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        calculateCirclePath()
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circleLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
        
        // Don't draw the circle initially
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.0
        
        // Add the circleLayer to the view's layer's sublayers
        self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
//MARK: - Private UI Setup Methods
    
    private func calculateCirclePath() {
        self.circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: size / 2, y: size / 2), radius: size / 3, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*2), clockwise: true)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        circleLayer.frame = self.layer.bounds
    }
    
    func animateCircle(duration: TimeInterval, repeats: Bool) {
        // Setup the CAShapeLayer with the path, colors, and line width
        // We want to animate the strokeEnd property of the circleLayer
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.repeatCount = repeats ? .infinity : 1
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeOut)
        circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        circleLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
        
        let rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotationAnimation.repeatCount = repeats ? .infinity : 1
        rotationAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotationAnimation.toValue = Double.pi*3
        rotationAnimation.duration = duration
        rotationAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        circleLayer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: nil)
        
        let fadeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
        fadeAnimation.repeatCount = repeats ? .infinity : 1
        fadeAnimation.fromValue = 1
        fadeAnimation.toValue = 0
        fadeAnimation.duration = duration
        fadeAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeIn)
        circleLayer.add(fadeAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

**Extension for ViewController**

```
extension ViewController {
    func startLoading() {
            view.addSubview(loadingView)
            loadingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                loadingView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
                loadingView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
                loadingView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(80)),
                loadingView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: CGFloat(80)),
            ])
        loadingView.isHidden = false
        loadingView.animateCircle(duration: 1, repeats: true)
    }
    
    func stopLoading() {
        loadingView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its better practice to call this method in main thread using dispatchQueue as sometime control may be in background thread so it must get returned to main thread before performing any UI updates